# Setting up a new project, intellij IDEA from compiled class files

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new to intellij IDEA, can some one give me any suggestions in creating a new project from already existing compiled class files?

FYI: I created an empty project, copied my class files in the out/production/ and then when creating a run configuration, i could not point to my main class.

Any ideas would be grateful.

Comment: Wait, you don't have sources available?

Comment: You may need to decompile the class files to produce source files For further info review http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Decompiler

Comment: @dimoniy: No, i do not have the source files, i only have the compiled class files

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a Project with just compiled classes, it doesn't make sense. IDEA wants the source code for the main class to run it, because when you think "run" Idea thinks "compile, then run".

If you just want to run the program, then you don't need IDEA at all for that.